# Unity icon issue and desktop icons not appearing

Tags: unity, login, launcher, icons, desktop-icons

[Screenshot of problems I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btonr.jpg)

Recently I have been having problems with my unity launcher and desktop. As you can see in the picture, when I log in, my desktop icons don't show up. My profile logs in, but the login box stays and my icons don't appear. It is not until I start Files that my icons return. What can I do to get my icons back without having to start the file explorer every time I start up?

Also, as seen in the picture, my unity launcher doesn't give launched app icons a coloured background like it used to, making it harder to see which programs are active in the background. In addition to that, the unity launcher is no longer partly translucent, showing the background underneath. How can I fix these other two issues?

Thanks.

Comment: my network firewall isn't allowing me view the screenShot...can you give some other screenShot's link ...!!

Comment: I have reuploaded [the screenshot](http://i40.tinypic.com/jgqu10.png). Has anyone any idea how I can fix these annoyances?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Restart and at the password prompt, click on the small ubuntu logo in the upper most right of the sign in box. click on the "cario-dock (gnome) and then continue to sign in.Your icons should appear. you may have something other than the above but it should return your desktop.